# Web Service Generated Code: Control serialized XML without unnecessary spaces and line breaks?

Tags: c#, web-services, web-config, xmlserializer

We have a web service that uses a code gened file for the message and operation contracts that was generated from the WSDL.  There is a request to remove all the formatting (whitespace, indention) from the serialized XML.    I know about the following settings:

```
settings.NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None;
settings.Indent = false;
```

Can I apply these in Web.Config with the `<System.Xml.Serialization>` config element?  All the serialization happens behind the scenes so I am wondering if I can control the formatting from the configuration file since we don't call the serialize method directly.

Or do I have to implement a custom xml serializer with those settings applied?

Comment: I'm curious, why would this be a requirement? Are you saying you want to remove indentation and whitespace from the XML that gets passed over the wire? If you have HTTP compression turned on, removing whitespace and indentation won't really get you anything, other than increasing the complexity of your code.

Comment: @rsbarro - Thanks, it came across my desk the other day.  Honestly if they are worried about space I would switch to JSON.  Thanks, for your comments about HTTP Compression.  I cannot find an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I gave:

The emitted XML looks fine as well as the code.  Because your class files for the messages are auto-generated, serialization is taken care of automatically.  You could re-work the code to do this part manually, but that would add un-needed complexity to the code.

Some options:

**Serialize manually.**

There are options to turn off certain formatting when you call serialization directly.  I don’t recommend this approach as other developers will wonder why this is being done.

**Turn on HTTP compression.**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression

Whitespace doesn’t matter when the messages are compressed.  I would recommend this anyway since your messages are 40-70 Meg (rather large).

**Use JSON**

JSON has a much smaller size payload as compared to the same XML message.  Since your message has lots of tags, the size drop should be significant even before compression.

Comment: If anyone finds an easy way to do this, post your answer and I will update and possibly accept.